# What's the Chinese equivalent of 将就? (成语)

Tags: chengyu

For Example:

> 正版 Windows 太贵了, 只能拿盗版Windows或Ubuntu**将就**一下了.

Which can be translated to

> Genuine Microsoft Windows is too expensive, I'll have to **make do** with pirated Windows or Ubuntu.

Are there any **Chengyus** similar to this?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. What's the Chinese equivalent? 将就 is Chinese, isn't it, albeit maybe topolectical? Or are you just asking what's the Chengyu equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [不得已而求其次](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E5%BE%97%E5%B7%B2%E8%80%8C%E6%B1%82%E5%85%B6%E6%AC%A1) or [将陋就简](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B0%86%E9%99%8B%E5%B0%B1%E7%AE%80).

Both have the same meaning with 将就 or 勉强凑合.

Comment: 退而求其次 is a varient of 不得已而求其次. *正版 Windows 太贵了, 只能退而求其次，用盗版Windows或Ubuntu.*